# From command line open package installer

Tags: macos, install, pkg

From the command line is it possible to open a package installer window (not install the application).

I understand I could run the application using `sudo installer -pkg ..... -target ......`. Instead i would like to open the package in a similar way to if I double clicked the package within the Finder.

Comment: Do you mean like entering open: /path/to/installer.pkg

Answer (score 6):

You can just use the open command:

```
open package.pkg
```

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i mean, cannot believe i missed it. Was expecting it to be a param of `installer`.